# How to change multiple images on multiple buttonclick using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner. I have searched a lot but didn't get a proper answer. I have 12 buttons on one view controller and want to set 12 images on click of respective button on different view controller on Imageview. I am frustrated as to how go about it, should i use an array for images or buttons?Please help me with an example.

Comment: can you explain more for this line **want to set 12 images on click of respective button on different view controller on Imageview**

Comment: did my answer help? if so, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1) Set tag value for each button
2) Add button action to each button
3) Create Image array

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1:UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2:UIButton!
.
.
.
@IBOutlet weak var button12:UIButton!

let imgList = ["imgName1","imgName2",.....,"imgName12"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button1.tag = 1
        button1.addTarget(self, action: "BtnImgChng:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        button2.tag = 2
        button2.addTarget(self, action: "BtnImgChng:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        .
        .
        .
        button12.tag = 12
        button12.addTarget(self, action: "BtnImgChng:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


}

func BtnImgChng(sender:UIButton)
    {
       sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "\(imgList[sender.tag])"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you have multiple view controllers of the same type and that tapping a button in one view controller should change the images that are set in the next view controller that might be displayed, here's what you can do.

1. Create two (or more) static array of arrays property in the view controller where each item in the array is another array of image names.
2. Create a static index which is the index into this array.
3. When a button is tapped in the view controller set this static index property to the next item in the array or any item in the array based on your logic.
4. In the view controller's viewDidLoad determine which array of images should be used to set the button images using this static index property.

E.g.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController
{
   static var indexIntoImagesArray:Int = 0
   static var arrayOfImages = [ ["button0_0.png", "button0_1.png", ..."button0_11.png"],
["button1_0.png", "button1_1.png", ..."button1_11.png"]]

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    let imagesArr = ViewController.arrayOfImages[ViewController .indexIntoImagesArray]
    setButtonImagesFromArray(imagesArr)
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender:AnyObject?)
{
  ViewController.indexIntoImagesArray = ViewController.indexIntoImagesArray == 0 ? 1 : 0 //toggles the index between 0 and 1.
}
}
```

You can use this strategy depending on the number of view controllers that you want to with different images.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I set up my enviornment in story board[image]

then I added the images I'm gonna dispaly here
[image]

the first one is the view controller and here is the code for it with comments

```
import UIKit

//setting the image needed
var currentImage = ""

class ViewController: UIViewController {


let imagesInOrder = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png"]

//once the button, is pressed do the following
@IBAction func button1Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    //set the image
    currentImage = imagesInOrder[0]

    //the name of the Segue connecting ViewController with imageViewController
    performSegueWithIdentifier("toIMG", sender: nil)

}

@IBAction func button2Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentImage = imagesInOrder[1]

    performSegueWithIdentifier("toIMG", sender: nil)

}


@IBAction func button3Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentImage = imagesInOrder[2]

    performSegueWithIdentifier("toIMG", sender: nil)


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

and the code for the imageView controller is basically:

```
import UIKit


class imageViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: currentImage)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

code for the entire project can be found here: 
[project link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdrnakst10wwkrd/buttonAPP.zip?dl=0)